# index out of range in self -> Applying pre-trained model on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to apply sentiment analysis into a pandas dataframe with tweets. And i'm getting the error

> `IndexError: index out of range in self`.

Sample dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14GuN3krdNhGDQCLShn3I6FJG-b5Zt02Z/view?usp=sharing

How im trying:

```py
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from transformers import pipeline
tqdm.pandas()

sample = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
model_name = 'finiteautomata/bertweet-base-sentiment-analysis'

classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model=model_name)

def sentiment_analysis(row):
    r = classifier(row.text)[0]
    return [r['label'], r['score']]
    
df_sample.progress_apply(sentiment_analysis, axis=1)
```

Some tweets returns me the error: `IndexError: index out of range in self`. I'm not really sure why.

[image]

This time happened on tweet 78.

Answer (score 0):

you need to truncate the sentences with `truncating = True`

```
def sentiment_analysis(row):
    r = classifier(row.text,truncation=True)[0]
    return [r['label'], r['score']]
```